# Create spring bean based on cmd line input

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to create a bean with the values of string parameters provided in cmd line

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataProvider getDataProvider(String filePath, String mnhPath) throws Exception {
        return new DataProvider(filePath, mnhPath);
    }
}


@SpringBootApplication
public class SomeApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SomeApplication .class, args);
    }

        @Override
        public void run(final String... args) throws Exception {
            final CommandLineArgs arguments = new CommandLineArgs();
            CmdLineParser parser = new CmdLineParser(arguments);
            parser.parseArgument(args);
            DataProvider dataProvider = beanFactory.getBean(DataProvider.class, arguments.one(), arguments.two());
            dataProvider.doSomeOperation();
    
        }
    }
```

But I am getting an error

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.tomtom.display.height.HeightsDataProvider required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.
```

How should I correctly configure the bean?

Comment: if you want to "create a bean" (in your runner): then you should not declare/initialize it in config. (who sets the initial `String filePath, String mnhPath` ?? (nobody) that's what causes the error (message)). If you want to "get a bean", then ensure `String filePath, String mnhPath` are set! (not via constructor (->auto-wired), but via `@Value`(/or constant) string fields.)

Comment: You could instead simply have your bean implement [CommandLineRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html) or [ApplicationRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationRunner.html)…

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to work if you try to create a bean of the format, and attempt at retrieving it.

```
@Bean
public Bean myBean(String xyz){
  return new Bean(xyz);
}
```

You could bypass this limitation by doing the following:

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class MyBeanExample{
        private String hello;
        private String world;
    }
```

---

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

        @Bean
        public MyBeanExample myBeanExample(){
            return new MyBeanExample();
        }

    
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

            MyBeanExample beanWithArgs = ctx.getBean(MyBeanExample.class);
            beanWithArgs.setHello(args[0]);
            beanWithArgs.setWorld(args[1]);

            System.out.println(beanWithArgs.getHello());
            System.out.println(beanWithArgs.getWorld());
        }
}
```

This would retrieve your `@Bean myBeanExample()` and then you use setters to set the parameters you need.

Comment: yes but before ```main``` method ```getDataProvider``` bean creation step gets called and there it fails as value is still not set.

Comment: My code has been tested.  Please try it

Comment: You won't be able to create the been with arguments.  Please see my example